# Oracle Cloud, access Flask Server on Compute Instance from Autonomous Database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I build a Flask Python REST app on a Oracle Cloud compute instance. The REST Call works from my client just fine. (I added Ingress Rule for 0.0.0.0/0).

My plan is to have the Comupute Instance only accesible from my ATP Database and call the REST Service from PL/SQL. When I try to call the Webservice, I get the following error:

```
    DECLARE
        l_clob  CLOB;
    BEGIN
       
        l_clob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
           p_url => 'https://130.zz.yy.xx:5000/test',
            --p_url=> 'https://httpbin.org/get',
            p_http_method => 'GET'
            );

END;

Error report -
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1182
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 782
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1209
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 756
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1023
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1371
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 568
ORA-06512: at line 5
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

Normal REST Calls work just fine. What could be the problem?

1. The ATP can not access the compute instance because of some network settings?
2. ATP is not happy with the SSL settings or some other nasty HTTPS stuff?

Comment: Did you follow the required setup as described in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/autonomous-database-shared/doc/call-web-services.html#GUID-FFF2F734-090F-4914-88E2-8A9B2C8C18B5)?

Comment: Yes, see the answer @Carsten provided, it seems not possible atm

Answer (score 0):

The restrictions of calling REST APIs from APEX on autonomous database are outlined here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpgs/autonomous-apex-web-services.html

So ...

- must be a public endpoint, and the SSL certificate must be provided by a public CA.
- For HTTPS, only the default port (443) is allowed; other ports raise the error message you're seeing.
- configuring a proxy server in APEX is not supported on ADB; you then also
  get the "Insufficient Privileges" error.

Comment: Hi Carsten, Thanks for your answer. So it seems like it's technically not possible to have such kind of "microservice" running on Oracle Cloud? The only way seems to get a domain + SSL certificate, put the server on the public internet and then call it via HTTPS REST Call. I would much prefer to keep the compute instance private for security reasons.

Comment: The doc I pointed to above says you can submit http requests to private ips. So maybe it will be feasible but only using utl_http and not the apex calls. And the port must be 443

Comment: Yes - you might check out this link, which explicitly talks about setting up networking to private endpoints: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/network-private-endpoint-enhanced.html#GUID-8FCA06C0-E1C1-49F6-82C2-6B7B3787CF3B